# Can I operate an arduino that has a file uploaded on it, without having the file myself?

Tags: serial, arduino-ide

I've been a massive idiot and accidentally deleted the sketch I need for a project at university, and I didn't create any backups. The sketch is already uploaded into the arduino, which operates using the serial monitor; when "1" is entered it does one thing, when "2" is entered it does another thing and so on. My question is: can I still use the serial monitor to operate the arduino without having the original sketch?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can. The serial monitor has nothing to do with the sketch - it's just a very primitive serial interface program.

You don't even need the serial monitor. You can use any serial interface program ("terminal emulator") such as Teraterm, Putty, Hyperterminal, etc.